# postgresql - export select query result using command

Tags: sql, postgresql

As we can take a backup file of database using pg_dump command, similarly can we take backup of a select query result.

For example if i have a query `select * from tablename;` then i want to take backup result of the query that can be restored somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like

```
copy (select * from tablename) to 'path/to/file';
```

it will generate csv file with results very same manner as `pg_dump` does (in fact in plain mode it actually runs `COPY` commands)

**update**

and if you want DDL as well, you can

```
create table specname as select * from tablename
```

and then

```
pg_dump -s specname
```